# Async call blocking main thread when using DispatchGroup

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to get documents from a FireStore database. I need these documents to be loaded before moving forward in my function. Here is the code for reference:

The view controller calling the FireStore service functions:

```
    let service = FirestoreServices()
    service.get(cottage: "test123456789") { model in
        
        nextViewController.cottageModel = model!
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
        
    }
```

The FireStore service method being called:

```
func get(cottage: String, completionHandler: @escaping (CottageTrip?) -> ()) {
    
    //get a reference to the firestore
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    //get the references to the collections
    let cottageRef = db.collection("cottages").document(cottage)
    
    //get the fields from the initial document and load them into the cottage model
    cottageRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            
            //create the cottage model to return
            let cottageModel: CottageTrip = CottageTrip()
            
            //get the subcollections of this document
            let attendeesCollection = cottageRef.collection("attendees")
            //other collections
            
            //here I get all info from initial document and store it in the model
            
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            
            print("here")
            
            group.enter()
            
            //get the attendees
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                
                attendeesCollection.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                    print("here2")
                    if let err = err {
                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        //get data
                    }
                    group.leave()
                }
                
            }
            
            print("after async call")
            
            //wait here until the attendees list is built
            group.wait()
            
            print("after wait")
            
            //create the cars
            carsCollection.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                print("in car collection get doc call")
                if let err = err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    //get car data
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //this is where she should block until all previous get document operations complete
            
            completionHandler(cottageModel)
            
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I am realizing that the `print("here2")` never prints so it seems like it blocks on the `group.wait()`. I need to use `group.wait()` rather than a notify because I need this function to access subcollections and documents only after the attendees collection is loaded as I need these values for the subcollections and documents. I have read a lot of answers online and most people use `group.wait()` in this scenario but for some reason I can not get it to work for me without locking and freezing the application.

Comment: You call wait() and it blocks your main thread until leave() is called. But it never gets called because the completion closure for your getDocuments() also needs main thread to run on. You have a deadlock there.

Comment: I don't see any point in using a dispatch group based on the code you provided because it appears that all the tasks executed to create a cottage model are already in serial. First you get the document and then you query the subcollection and then you do `x` and then you do `y`. All of this is already in serial so just nest them as you do and if at any point something fails (like a missing document or a network error), return `nil` in the completion handler and move on.

Comment: @bsod These two `getDocuments` calls are asynchronous, so if you want to let them run concurrently, you do need the group to know when both are done. If, however, you need the results from one for the other, then you are correct, you can run one after the other by nesting them, eliminating the need for the group.

Answer (score 1):

As algrid pointed out, you have a deadlock because you are waiting on the main thread, which Firestore needs to call its closures.

As a general rule, avoid calling `wait` and you will not deadlock. Use `notify`, and just call your closure inside that `notify` closure.

So, for example, assuming that you do not need the results from `attendees` in order to query the `cars`, you can just use a `notify`  dispatch group pattern, e.g.

```swift
func get(cottage: String, completionHandler: @escaping (CottageTrip?) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let cottageRef = db.collection("cottages").document(cottage)

    cottageRef.getDocument { document, error in
        guard let document = document, document.exists else {
            print("Document does not exist")
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }

        let cottageModel = CottageTrip()

        let attendeesCollection = cottageRef.collection("attendees")
        let carsCollection = cottageRef.collection("cars")

        let group = DispatchGroup()

        group.enter()
        attendeesCollection.getDocuments() { querySnapshot, err in
            defer { group.leave() }

            ...
        }

        group.enter()
        carsCollection.getDocuments() { querySnapshot, err in
            defer { group.leave() }

            ...
        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            completionHandler(cottageModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as an aside, but you do not have to dispatch anything to a global queue, as these methods are already asynchronous.

---

If you needed the result from one in order to initiate the next, you can just nest them. This will be slower (because you magnify the network latency effect), but also eliminates the need for the group at all:

```swift
func get(cottage: String, completionHandler: @escaping (CottageTrip?) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let cottageRef = db.collection("cottages").document(cottage)

    cottageRef.getDocument { document, error in
        guard let document = document, document.exists else {
            print("Document does not exist")
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }

        let cottageModel = CottageTrip()

        let attendeesCollection = cottageRef.collection("attendees")
        let carsCollection = cottageRef.collection("cars")

        attendeesCollection.getDocuments() { querySnapshot, err in
            ...

            carsCollection.getDocuments() { querySnapshot, err in
                ...

                completionHandler(cottageModel)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Either way, I might be inclined to break this up into separate functions, as it is a little hairy, but the idea would be the same.